# VS Code TypeScript SourceMaps Via TSC Not Working

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, source-maps, tsc

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I can't hit any breakpoints in any of my TS files please? The application is a Node.JS app and is transpiled with TSC. Below is an example of the entry app.ts file:

**./src/app.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

import kernel from './ioc'
import { IServer } from './utilities/abstract/IServer'

let server = kernel.get<IServer>("IServer");
server.start();
```

**./src/app.js**

```
"use strict";
require('reflect-metadata');
var ioc_1 = require('./ioc');
var server = ioc_1.default.get("IServer");
server.start();

//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

**./src/app.js.map**

```
{"version":3,"file":"app.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["app.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";AAAA,QAAO,kBAAkB,CAAC,CAAA;AAE1B,oBAAmB,OACnB,CAAC,CADyB;AAG1B,IAAI,MAAM,GAAG,aAAM,CAAC,GAAG,CAAU,SAAS,CAAC,CAAC;AAC5C,MAAM,CAAC,KAAK,EAAE,CAAC"}
```

**./tsonfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

**./.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app.js",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": null
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the launch configuration it breakpoints in the JS file, not the TS file. Also breakpoints in the TS file give me the following tooltip:

[image: TS Breakpoint error]

I'd really like my TS and JS to reside in different directories and use Gulp to do the transpiling but wanted to get this simple set up working first. Is it just a case of TS breakpoints in VS Code being pretty flakey or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Add launch.json to root folder with configuration below

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch type",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "src/app.ts",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "bin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a link for reference https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I don't have a bin folder. As I mentioned I'm trying to get it all working on in one directory at the moment before splitting it.